# LOGIN form and REGISTRATION form in the same TEMPLATE

Tags: forms, symfony, authentication, controller, registration

I'm trying to make a page **including** the **login** form and the **registration** form.

After doing a
make:user,
make:form (RegisterType),
make:auth (SecurityController).

The connection form is executed perfectly but the registration form does not send to the database and refreshes the page.

If anyone has a solution?
Thank you !

RegisterType :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;

class RegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'constraints' => new Length([
                    'min' => 2,
                    'max' => 33
                ]),
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form__input',
                    'placeholder' => 'Votre prénom'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('lastname', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'constraints' => new Length([
                    'min' => 2,
                    'max' => 33
                ]),
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form__input',
                    'placeholder' => 'Votre nom'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('email', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => EmailType::class,
                'invalid_message' => "L'adresse email et la confirmation doivent être identique.",
                'required' => true,
                'first_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form__input',
                        'placeholder' => 'votre@email.com'
                    ]
                ],
                'second_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form__input',
                        'placeholder' => 'Confirmer votre adresse email'
                    ]
                ]
            ])
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'Le mot de passe et la confirmation doivent être identique.',
                'required' => true,
                'first_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form__input',
                        'placeholder' => 'Votre mot de passe'
                    ]
                ],
                'second_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form__input',
                        'placeholder' => 'Confirmer votre mot de passe'
                    ]
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

SecurityController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\LoginType;
use App\Form\RegisterType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/connexion", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils, Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $hasher): Response
    {
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegisterType::class, $user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user = $form->getData();

            $password = $hasher->hashPassword($user, $user->getPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);

            $this->entityManager->persist($user);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/deconnexion", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout(): void
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

Template (login.html.twig):

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Connexion{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="connexion__container">
        <div class="connexion__forms">
            <div class="connexion__forms-form">

                <form name="login" method="post" class="connexion__form-connexion">
                    <h2 class="connexion__form-title">Connectez vous</h2>
                    <div class="connexion__form-input">
                        <i class="uil uil-user"></i>
                        <input type="email" value="{{ last_username }}" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" autocomplete="email" placeholder="votre@email.com" required autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class="connexion__form-input">
                        <i class="uil uil-padlock"></i>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" placeholder="Votre mot de passe" required>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
                    <button class="connexion__form-button" type="submit">Connexion</button>
                </form>

                {{ form_start(form, {'attr' : {'class' : 'connexion__form-register'} }) }}
                    <h2 class="connexion__form-title">Inscrivez vous</h2>

                    <div class="connexion__form-input">
                        <i class="uil uil-user"></i>
                        {{ form_widget(form.firstname) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="connexion__form-input">
                        <i class="uil uil-user"></i>
                        {{ form_widget(form.lastname) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="connexion__form-input">
                        <i class="uil uil-envelope"></i>
                        {{ form_widget(form.email.first) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="connexion__form-input">
                        <i class="uil uil-envelope"></i>
                        {{ form_widget(form.email.second) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="connexion__form-input">
                        <i class="uil uil-padlock"></i>
                        {{ form_widget(form.password.first) }}
                    </div>

                    <div class="connexion__form-input">
                        <i class="uil uil-padlock"></i>
                        {{ form_widget(form.password.second) }}
                    </div>
                    {{ form_rest(form) }}
                    <button class="connexion__form-button" type="submit">S'inscrire</button>
                {{ form_end(form) }}


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="connexion__options-container">
            <div class="connexion__option connexion__option-left">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Première visite ?</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis,
                        ex ratione. Aliquid!
                    </p>
                    <button class="connexion__form-button connexion__form-buttonAlt" id="connexion__button-register">
                        Inscrivez vous
                    </button>
                </div>

                <img src="{{ asset('assets/img/register.svg') }}" class="image" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div class="connexion__option connexion__option-right">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Vous êtes déjà membre ?</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum
                        laboriosam ad deleniti.
                    </p>
                    <button class="connexion__form-button connexion__form-buttonAlt" id="connexion__button-connexion">
                        Connectez vous
                    </button>
                </div>

                <img src="{{ asset('assets/img/log.svg') }}" class="image" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Do you have any error ? What did you do to debug ? Do you receive the data in your controller ? Have you tried to work with only the registration form ?

Comment: Hello @TimZwinkels ! I have no errors. The page reloads when I click on the button subscribe.I have a RegisterController with a registration page and on this page everything works.